# Revolution Slider Carousel loads tiny

Tags: wordpress, carousel, revolution-slider

I implemented a rev slider in my wordpress site and im not very impressed.

The first carousel slider loads okay on page load but the next batch of carousel sliders seems to take ages before it assumes the actual size. Here is a snapshot to explain better.

This is the first carousel slider on the tab and displays by default on page load which looks great.

[image]

This second one on the secon tab just doesnt load quite right and will last forever in this size unless i refrest the page many times. Not cool at all.

[image]

I have the feeling i missed some configuration but cant seem to get any help throug google searches and will appreciate all the help i can get.

Thaks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a configuration issue but script conflict issue happening because sliders are in tabs so initially first tab content is visible while others are hidden so technically content of 2nd tab has 0 height. And since slider calculates the space it is going to occupy dynamically, it gets smaller height as tab scripts are loaded a bit after slider scripts are. Try contacting ThemePunch support and ask them for **redraw code** which will redraw slider using slider API forcing slider to force reload upon page load, resulting in loading slider properly the first time.

Comment: Hi @Masood. Thanks for your response. I got this [link](https://www.themepunch.com/revsliderjquery-doc/api/) from ThemePunch support and will like to know how to go about the implementation. So i inserted the code below into a custom JS box in my theme. Now on each page that displays the carousel slider in the tab, i need to call the redraw but how do i do that? and where must i replace #sliderid with the actual sliders id?   
'var revapi;
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
   revapi = jQuery("#sliderid").revolution({
   ...
   });
});'